# Objective C - NSString working but plist string doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, plist

I have a piece of code that finds a random word in a plist and then assigns it to the NSString 'correctWord'. For some reason the code works fine in one instance but doesn't work in another.

This code works:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                  @"small" ofType:@"plist"];

NSArray *plistArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSInteger randV = arc4random_uniform(plistArray.count); // randV is from 0 to number of strings -1 in array
[super viewDidLoad];
self.correctWord = @"Hello"; //<--- Code works fine here..
[self setupHangmanWord:self.correctWord];
}
```

This code doesn't work. (there are no errors in the compiler though)

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                  @"small" ofType:@"plist"];

NSArray *plistArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSInteger randV = arc4random_uniform(plistArray.count); // randV is from 0 to number of strings -1 in array
[super viewDidLoad];
self.correctWord = [plistArray objectAtIndex:randV]; //<--- Doesn't work anymore.
[self setupHangmanWord:self.correctWord];
}
```

Comment: What is the nature of "doesn't work"?

Comment: PlistArray contains array of NSdictionary s.

Comment: Show the structure of your `small.plist` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"small" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: I get an error here now: self.correctWord = [plistDict objectAtIndex:randV];